# Нужно ли тире в следующем предложении?

Tags: тире

В предложении: «Закинули в соцсеть – и вуаля!» А далее идет, что нашли нужную информацию и т. д. Склоняюсь к тире!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно склоняетесь, поскольку часть «и вуаля!» является результатом/выводом из того, что содержится в первой части «Закинули в соцсеть» (смотрите [§ 171](https://therules.ru/dash/#171)).